# session destroy works but i need to press F5 each time to see the new update is there any solution?

Tags: php, session

when i log in i redirect in the home page and when i press logout i destroy my

session and redirect in same page with new updates but only when i press F5

layout.php

```
          <?php
  session_start();
  if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {?>
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="?controller=user&action=inscription">Inscription</a></li>
    <li class="login">
      <div id="loginContainer"><a id="loginButton"><span>Se Connecter</span></a>
        <div id="loginBox" style="display: none;">                
          <form id="loginForm"  method="POST" action="?controller=user&action=authentification">
            <fieldset id="body">
              <fieldset>
                <label>Login</label>
                <input type="text" name="login" id="email" >   
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>
                <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
              </fieldset>
              <input type="submit" id="login" value="Connexion" name="xxl1">
              <label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"> <i>Rester Connecté</i></label>
            </fieldset>
            <span><a href="#">Mot de passe oublié?</a></span>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
 <?php 
 } else { $name = $_SESSION['login'] 
 ?>
  <h1  style="
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  ">
   Bonjour <?php echo $name ?>
    </h1>
  <a href="?controller=user&action=dashboard" style="
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  "> Editer mon profil
   </a>
   <a href="?controller=user&action=deconnexion" style="
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin-right: -1px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  "> Deconnexion
   </a>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

User.php

```
            public static function Deco()
{
  @session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['login'];  
 unset($_SESSION["login"]);
 unset($_SESSION["motdepasse"]);
  session_destroy();
   $_SESSION= array();
  echo " C BON tout est vide  ";
    ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href ="?controller=accueil&action=home";
      </script>
      <?php   

}
```

user_controller.php

```
              public function deconnexion() 
           {
                  $client = User::Deco(); 
                    //require_once('index.php');

           }
```

if there is any solutions or any advices to make the my code better tell me

please

Comment: Better do an PHP redirect `header('Location: http://example.com/?controller=accueil&action=home');exit;`, you dont need to go to the client first and redirect there. maybe your problem is fixed by that.

Comment: can u explain me the exit; at the end please ?

Comment: When you redirect on server side, normally nothing should run after the redirect, so normally you add an exit after the `header()` line. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: i did what you've told me to do but still same thing didn't work i still need to press F5 :/

Answer (score 0):

To destroy the session you should do:

```
$_SESSION = array();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

After that, redirect the user to other page - it can be done using js after checking for session variable.

From the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php):

> "In order to kill the session altogether, the session ID must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session ID (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that."

You can see how they destroy the cookie at the same link:

```
// If it's desired to kill the session, also delete the session cookie.
// Note: This will destroy the session, and not just the session data!
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}
```

Try it and see if it helps.

Comment: the session is destroyed but i need to press F5 each time to see the new update

Comment: Added cookie deletion information - test it whenever you can.